# A little advice regarding large amounts of comma deliminated data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, types

I need some advice regarding comma-delimited values and SQL performance.

Q: if I have 1M comma-delimited records on a single table will there be a major performance hit when I split the values? (obviously there will be performance issue when running view on 1M records).

Q: If comma-delimited is not good, what other alternatives exist to deal with information of this nature? (this data will be used to filter and display other information on an admin dashboard).

Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: **YES**, comma-delimited strings are awful, they violate even the **first normal form** of database design, they come back to haunt you, they suck performance from your system - try to avoid them if ever possible! The **real solution** would be to use a proper **table** to hold the 1-n entries - that's what a relational database is good at doing!

Comment: @marc_s check this case - a large amount of records (ids) is inserted in a table constantly, and on each insert records that are older then 20 minutes are deleted. When the table become large (more then 25 millions records), the delete operation starts to take too much time. We have try to use batch delete, creating proper indexes, etc. Nothing help to optimize the delete. Then we try to use insert one record with `CSV` with the IDs. The differences between extracting 100 000 rows or one row with 100 000 ids and converting them to rows was 1 second but with delete latency fixed.

Answer (score 0):

> if I have 1M comma-delimited records on a single table will there be a major performance hit when I split the values?

Yes, you are right. Its not a good idea to use this. Try to avoid this.

Instead of storing comma separated values, you can use a table to hold all the values row by row instead of storing as comma separated in one row. It will increase the performance of the system and also it will serve the purpose for what database was invented.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "information of this nature". If the information is consistent, then a standard relational table is what you should use. If, on the other hand, the data is heterogeneous (mixed, not the same), perhaps varying row by row based on requirements, then you might consider using xml, which can be indexed. For example; the two csv rows below could be represented instead as shown in an xml column. This is just one way to do this, but it shows a way of using xml to structured but heterogenous data in an indexable manner.

```
declare @csv table(
  [data]     [sysname]
  , [filter] [sysname]);
 insert into @csv
        ([data],[filter])
 values      (N'data that needs to be filtered',N'a,b,c,d'),
        (N'data that needs to be filtered',N'e,f,g,h');
 select [data]
   , [filter] -- some awfully slow filtering function applies here
 from   @csv;
 --
 declare @xml table (
   [data]     [sysname]
   , [filter] [xml]);
 insert into @xml
        ([data],[filter])
 values      (N'data that needs to be filtered',N'<data>
  <filter>a</filter>
  <filter>b</filter>
  <filter>c</filter>
  <filter>d</filter>
</data>'),
        (N'data that needs to be filtered',N'<data>
  <filter>a</filter>
  <filter>b</filter>
  <filter>c</filter>
  <filter>d</filter>
</data>');
select [data]
   , cast(t.c.query(N'./text()') as [sysname])
from   @xml
   cross apply [filter].nodes(N'/data/filter') as t(c);
```